# Dual-parent nested resources or is polymorphism right for me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I have a model called `evaluation` that `belongs_to` two other models - `student` and `goal`.

While researching how to set up this association for routing, at first I thought a polymorphic association would be best, but now I'm not so sure.  My understanding of polymorphic relationships isn't that sturdy, so please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that in my case `evaluations` could `belong_to` `student` or `goal` equally, but that's not really what I want.

In fact, it's important that a given `evaluation` `belong_to` both a `student` **and** a `goal` simultaneously.  The [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) makes specific mention that it's not a good idea to have triple nested resources:

[image: rails routing guide]

However, even this caveat is not helpful as in this example `photos` `belong_to` `magazines` which in turn `belong to` `publishers` - whereas in my case `evaluations` should `belong_to` both `students` and `goals` simultaneously.

I tried

```
resources :students, :goals do 
  resources :evaluations
end
```

but that only creates a resource for `students/evaluations` and `goals/evaluations` - so my question, then:

**How can I route to a nested resource that has equally-weighted belonging to two parent models (I only need Create, Update and Destroy actions, as `evaluations` will only ever be viewed in the context of one/both of the parent models)?**

OR

**Should I be doing this with a polymorphic association and I'm just not understanding it properly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [rmagnum2002](https://stackoverflow.com/users/985241/rmagnum2002) gave a very good answer regarding a solution using polymorphic associations, I wasn't able to make it work for me.  In the end I kept `evaluations` belonging_to `goals` and `students` dually.  As for routing, the relevant part of my `routes.rb` looks like this:

```
resources :students, :goals, :only => :stub do
  resources :evaluations, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
end
```

and generates:

```
student_evaluations POST   /students/:student_id/evaluations(.:format)                   evaluations#create
new_student_evaluation GET    /students/:student_id/evaluations/new(.:format)               evaluations#new
edit_student_evaluation GET    /students/:student_id/evaluations/:id/edit(.:format)          evaluations#edit
student_evaluation PUT    /students/:student_id/evaluations/:id(.:format)               evaluations#update
                       DELETE /students/:student_id/evaluations/:id(.:format)               evaluations#destroy
goal_evaluations POST   /goals/:goal_id/evaluations(.:format)                         evaluations#create
new_goal_evaluation GET    /goals/:goal_id/evaluations/new(.:format)                     evaluations#new
edit_goal_evaluation GET    /goals/:goal_id/evaluations/:id/edit(.:format)                evaluations#edit
goal_evaluation PUT    /goals/:goal_id/evaluations/:id(.:format)                     evaluations#update
                       DELETE /goals/:goal_id/evaluations/:id(.:format)                     evaluations#destroy
```

and most importantly generates an evaluation model in the database that looks like this:

[image: db view]

so for each `evaluation` there is a corresponding `goal_id` **and** `student_id` simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

I would use polymorphic:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :students do
  resources :evaluations
end

resources :goals do
  resources :evaluations
end
```

**models/evaluation.rb**

```
class Evaluation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :some_attribute
  belongs_to :evaluable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**models/student.rb**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :some_attribute
  has_many :evaluations, as: :evaluable
end
```

**models/goal.rb**

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :some_attribute
  has_many :evaluations, as: :evaluable
end
```

your relation between goal and student will look like:

```
id    evaluable_id  evaluable_type    other_field
 1               4       'Goal'         'other goal content 1'
 2               1       'Student'      'other student content 1'
 3               1       'Student'      'other student content 2'
```

now you can call:

```
Student.find(1).evaluations
```

will return evaluations with ids 2 and 3 as they have evaluable_type = Student where evaluable id = 1. Or:

```
Goal.find(4).evaluations
```

will return evaluation with id 1, guess why. :)
Yes, use polymorphic associations.

Comment: I'll give it a try.  What should the routes file look like?

Comment: @dax did this answer solved your issue? if not just let me know so I remove it.. no need to keep garbage on SO.

Comment: @magnum2002, i had a bit of an unplanned break, but I'm gonna get back to things sometime today.  I'll accept or add another answer today.  thanks for keeping track though!